# "Dictionary problem." Error with VMPlayer

Tags: virtualization, vmware-player

I'm pretty new to using vmware virtualization (been a virtualbox user) so I'm hoping you guys can help me out. I recently got an external usb disk containing a vm for a client, downloaded vmplayer, set it up with "Open a Virtual Machine", ran it, easy as pie.

After working with it a bit this morning, I shut the VM down and now trying to start it back up again I get this:
[image: Failed to open virtual machine: Dictionary problem.]

I tried removing the vm from my library, now it happens whenever I try to add it back in. In the meantime, I *can* still access other virtual machines so it seems like the problem might be with the virtual disk.

So two questions:

- This is obviously not a very helpful error message. Where can I go to get more information? My Application EventLog doesn't contain anything from VMWare.
- What steps can I take to fix the problem?

**Edit:** A couple more pieces of information.

- I did not take any snapshots. I don't think VM Player even has that ability.
- I have a zip file of (what I assume) is the state of the VM when it was sent to me. I cannot unzip it as it is huge and simply requires more HD space than I have available but I *did* extract the vmx file and examine it. Other than the UUIDs and the fact that mine reads `cleanShutdown = "FALSE"` they are identical.
- The log contains the following lines

  Jun 23 10:11:18.080: vmx| SNAPSHOT: SnapshotConfigInfoRead: Unable to load dict from 'E:....\MachineName.vmsd'.

  Jun 23 10:11:18.080: vmx| SNAPSHOT: SnapshotConfigInfoRead failed for file 'E:....\MachineName.vmx': Dictionary problem (6)

  Jun 23 10:11:18.082: vmx| SNAPSHOT: Snapshot_TimeStampTiers failed: Dictionary problem (6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record I got this fixed by taking backups of my `caches` directory, `vmsd, vmxf, vmx, nvram` files and copying them over the files that I had. I guess some of them had been corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Have seen this in relation to snapshots creatiung this error.  There are several threads in VMware community sites.  [VMware community](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1564428)
  Another thread here speaks to it as well [VM Discussions](http://discussions.virtualdr.com/showthread.php?t=230854)

Comment: Hmm, I have not taken any snapshots, I was not even aware that with Vm Player you could do this

Comment: I was thinking the VM you received may have had one with the VM

Comment: It might have, but I haven't done anything with them!

Answer (score 0):

Try at first load your virtual machine without any physical discs.

Then try to add it in VM->Settings->Add->Hard Disk->SCSI->Use physical disk->PhysicalDrive (your number, take a look at Disk management).

I had same problem, and solved it by adding physical disks on a loaded VM.